# Stripe Apps External Test Mode LInk Redirect Not Working

Tags: javascript, stripe-apps

I am developing a stripe app that includes oauth.  When using the external test mode link and installing the app it never redirects back to my development environment.  The live mode link works, but not the test mode.

When using the external test mode link it says "installing in live mode".  How do I install in test mode?  This is my app config

```
{
  "id": "com.example-io.example",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "name": "example",
  "icon": "./example.png",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "customer_read",
      "purpose": "Referencing customer data in notifications"
    },
    {
      "permission": "invoice_read",
      "purpose": "Referencing customer invoices in notifications"
    },
    {
      "permission": "webhook_read",
      "purpose": "Setting webhook URL in client portal"
    }
  ],
  "ui_extension": {
    "views": [
      {
        "viewport": "stripe.dashboard.drawer.default",
        "component": "DrawerDefaultView"
      },
      {
        "viewport": "settings",
        "component": "AppSettings"
      }
    ]
  },
  "allowed_redirect_uris": [
    "https://localhost:8080/settings/stripe/oauth/return",
    "https://weburl/settings/stripe/oauth/return"
  ],
  "stripe_api_access_type": "oauth",
  "distribution_type": "public"
}
```

I don't have anything else other than this uploaded. I've installed and activated for external test

[image: stripe settings]